# http://127.0.0.1:8000 Showing Laravel Official Site Documentation Page NOT Showing basic First Time Laravel Site

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am a beginner and in the learning phase of Laravel. So when I created a project for the first time inside my "laravel" folder present in E drive using command prompt then after creation it gives me a URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000) to access my first project
[Here is my Command prompt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkSlF.png).
But When I am accessing this URL it is showing me Laravel's Documentation page [I am seeing this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY1ts.png) whereas the Internet and all the sources which I am seeing and following it are showing a basic Laravel Site [This basic site is visible on all the sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EB4w.png)
Kindly guide me Why can't I am seeing this basic site  Whether I am doing right or is there anything wrong in my approach.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... that is the default welcome page for a fresh Laravel installation; you are using the new version

Comment: Nothing is wrong. That’s the new welcome screen as of Laravel 8.

Comment: Thanks @lagbox  for clearing my confusion.

Comment: Thanks @Unflux .So I should proceed forward towards learning Laravel.

Comment: Yup, nothing to worry about so proceed with your learning adventure.

Answer (score 0):

This is default code given by laravel in welcome.blade.php.
Delete default code and write your own code

Answer (score 0):

this is laravel 8 default page you have to customize the views according to your requirement.

Comment: I have understood your point Zeeshan.. Thanks